# Highcharts - Y axis always visible (even after horizontal scrolling)

Tags: highcharts

I am generating Highcharts column charts with many columns. The chart is very wide, necessitating scrolling (via the CSS overflow option on the Highcharts div). Is there a way for the Y axis to always be visible, even when one has scrolled to the right? I am aware that Highstock has an option for a scrollbar, but I'm only using Highcharts. Is there anything comparable there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add your code to a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable scrollbar in highcharts including highstock.js. but using highcharts. see example:  http://jsfiddle.net/xVyLr/

```
 xAxis: {
    max:5
 },
 scrollbar: {
    enabled:true
 },
```